# VB.NET System.Math Radius to Degree

Tags: vb.net

I am making a calculator on VB.net and I noticed that the `System.Math` library uses radians for calculating and I would like it to calculate in degrees. Is it possible to change that?

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
private function RadianToDegree(angle as double) as double
    return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI)
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET:

```
private double RadianToDegree(double angle) => angle * (180.0 / Math.PI)
private double DegreeToRadian(double radian) => radian * (Math.PI / 180.0)
```